# Retain html tags when copy/pasting to textarea

Tags: c#, html

I have a need for the user to select text in another (external) web page, and copy/paste it to a html textarea txaQuote (which has a runat server attribute).

I then capture the value as:

```
string quote = txaQuote.Value;
```

This however captures only the "text" - any html tags (if for example the source has any `<a>` tags or spans `<p></p>` tags) aren't preserved. is there any way to do so?

```
string quote = txaQuote.InnerHtml
```

and

```
string quote = txaQuote.InnerText
```

don't work, so I'm guessing the html is actually lost in the copy/paste process itself. Is there a way to preserve it?

Comment: just for info, dont you think this will allow cross browser scripting and can be potential threat, did you tried html encoding

Comment: yes, i have checks in place to prevent that. but part of the check is also that a)the url they say the quote is from exists (they have to provide that); & b)that the quote exists in the url - at present i can't verify b if there are any tags in the quote since it won't recognise the string.

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems to me the problem is with the textarea control itself, it's not rich text. By using the menulabs rich text box I can preserve the html.